# Ninject/DI With A Specific Implementation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, ninject

I have the following classes. I won't list out the interface, but assume that each public method is defined on the interface.

```
public class LabelRepo : ILabelRepo
{
    private readonly IApplicationContext _appContext;

    public IEnumerable<ILabel> GetAllLabels()
    {
        int userId = _appContext.UserId;

        //some code here to ask a database to get me all labels belonging to the user Id;

        return listOfLabelsForThatUser; 
    }

    public LabelRepo(IApplicationContext appContext)
    {
        _appContext = appContext;
    }
}

public class ApplicationContext : IApplicationContext
{
    public int UserId { get; }

    public ApplicationContext(IUser user)
    {
       UserId = user.UserId;
    }
}

And User : IUser is someObject with fields userId, username, etc...
```

The issue Im having is this:

```
public ActionResult Login(string username, string password)
{
     IUser user = _serviceThatValidates(username, password);
     return RedirectToAction("See", "MethodBelow");
}

public ActionResult MethodBelow()
{

    var labels = _labelRepo.GetAllLabels();
}
```

It seems that `_labelRepo` has an `ApplicationContext` that contains a null `IUser`, which kinda makes sense. Is there a way that I can tell the NinjectKernel to use that `IUser` in the login method and give it to the `ApplicationContext`?

Also this is the only instance of `IUser` that exists.

Comment: They're different HTTP Requests. You'd pull an IUser instance from the current HttpContext. How are you registering IUser? Are you using .InRequestScope()? https://github.com/ninject/Ninject/wiki/Object-Scopes

Comment: Prevent injecting [runtime data into application components](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=99).